# Can I use Visual Studio 2013 Web Express to develop commercial website?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

It is free to use VS 2013 Express to develop commercial website using MVC and Web Api.
 as these both are open source?

Is it available for free download or it only for 30 day trial?

Comment: Duplicate of http://www.visualstudio.com/en-US/products/visual-studio-express-vs

Comment: Yes, no problem.  There used to be a clause in the EULA that prohibited creating a service that you re-sell to others but that's been dropped in the last few I looked at.  Read the EULA you see when you start the installer.  It is free, not a trial, you have to register to activate.  It is not open source, what you do with your own source code is entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2013 Express for Web is free to download. Although after the 30 day trial, you will need to login with a MS account and register your product.

There are also many other free IDE's that you can use to develop a commercial website, and you can find them with a simple Google search.